# Combining SUM(), GROUP_BY() and LEFT_JOIN() returns incorrect results: how to fix?

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I am writing a query that should return aggregated hours for multiple users per day/month/year.

The table looks something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| id | entity_id | minutes | person | date |
+------------------------------------------+
```

**How output *should* look:**

```
+----------------------------+
| year | month | day | hours |
| 2008 | 12    | 1   | 30    |
| 2008 | 12    | 2   | 40    |
| 2008 | 12    | 3   | 23    |
+----------------------------+
```

Instead, the `hours` are often a lot more due to the returned rows caused by the `left join`.

The problem is that I need to query this table based on the tags that are linked to the corresponding entities. When I join the two tables (`tag_entity` that provides the link and `tags` that provides the actual tag names) my `SUM()` no longer works since there are too many results being returned.

**The query:**

```
select 
    date_format(from_unixtime(date), '%Y-%m-%d') as myDate,
    ROUND(SUM(time) / 60,1) as hours

from time h

left join tag_entity te on te.entity_id = h.entity_id
left join tags t on t.tag_id = te.tag_id

where (t.tag_name NOT IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz') OR t.tag_name IS NULL) 

group by
    myDate

order by
    hours DESC, myDate ASC
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Here are the schemas for `tag` and `tag_entity`:

`Tag`:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| tag_id   | int(11)     |
| tag_name | varchar(50) |
+----------+-------------+
```

And `tag_entity`:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Field     | Type    |
+-----------+---------+
| id        | int(11) |
| tag_id    | int(11) |
| entity_id | int(11) |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet, but I'm having trouble deducing your schema.  Could you post the relevant parts of the schemas for tags and tag_entity?  Also, in which table is "date" and "time" defined?

Comment: @Andrew thanks for replying. I added the schemas. `date` and `time` is in my `time` table.

Comment: You're selecting `from t` and doing `left join tags t` - syntax error. Did you forget to put in the main table name?

Comment: @Marc oops. Posted query is somewhat adjusted and this problem does not occur in the original one. Will fix in this example.

Comment: Do you want entities without one of the tags ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), or do you want entities that contain a tag other than ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')? If entity 1 has tag 'foo' and tag 'me', should it be included or not?

Comment: Since the column in the `time` table is `hours`, what exactly is `SUM(time)/60` summing up?  The division by 60 suggests that something is being recorded in minutes.

Comment: @Jonathan correct `hours` is just meta here. Changed it to `minutes` to clear that up.

Comment: @jswolf I actually want to simulate both cases. The example above should only return rows in the `time` table that are *not* linked to one of those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` groups the **results**, not the table rows individually.

Based on your comment *only return rows in the time table that are not linked to one of those tags*:

```
SELECT 
    date_format(from_unixtime(date), '%Y-%m-%d') as myDate,
    ROUND(SUM(time) / 60,1) as hours
FROM `time` h
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT te.entity_id
    FROM tag_entity te
      LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tag_id = te.tag_id
    WHERE te.entity_id IS NOT NULL AND t.tag_name IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
  ) g ON h.entity_id = g.entity_id
WHERE g.entity_id IS NULL
group by
    myDate

order by
    hours DESC, myDate ASC
```

Comment: Woa you actually nailed it. Thanks so much, you just made my weekend.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    date_format(from_unixtime(date), '%Y-%m-%d') as jaar,
    ROUND(SUM(time) / 60,1) as uren

from time h

left join tag_entity te on te.entity_id = h.entity_id
left join tags t on t.tag_id = te.tag_id

where (t.tag_name NOT IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz') OR t.tag_name IS NULL) 

group by jaar

order by
    uren DESC, jaar ASC
```

Comment: Apart from changing the date format into one column, this solves nothing. To simplify the query I changed it to return only one date column, though.

Comment: Did you test it? It is not just the date format change. The problem with you query is that you are grouping by the months off all years and the days of all months and years, say, the sum of all januaries from all years. It has nothing to do with the left join. Apart from that don't you mean `AND t.tag_name IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: yeah I tested it, without results, sadly. The GROUP BY clause should not work the way you describe: it combines group arguments. Your example results in the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like this:

```
select 
    date_format(from_unixtime(date), '%Y-%m-%d') as myDate,
    ROUND(SUM(time) / 60,1) as hours

from time h
```

<strike>`left join tag_entity te on te.entity_id = h.entity_id`</strike>

```
where NOT EXISTS(select te.entity_id

                 from tag_entity te

                 join tags t on t.tag_id = te.tag_id

                 where te.tag_entity = h.entity_id  AND t.tag_name IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')) 

group by
    myDate

order by
    hours DESC, myDate ASC
```